# vim - undo across all buffers / windows / open files etc

Tags: vim

In vim, I would like to undo through *all* changes in *all* buffers, in chronological order.

e.g., in a vim session I typically have many tabs open, with many windows in each tab. Using `u` to undo (or `g;` / `g,` to move though the changelist), vim moves through changes made to *that* buffer, even if there are more recent made changes in other buffers. (Which I admit, is what I want most of the time.)

But is there a way to move back through changes in all buffers in chronological order? (I imagine vim would jump around from tab to tab, which would be ok.)

Why would this be useful? ... mostly so when I resume coding after a break I can remind myself of "where I'm up to", i.e all the changes I made last time.

(Using macvim 7.3)

UPDATE: responses about using git / mercurial make good points (thanks especially for `git stash`), but I'd still find this feature useful as it steps me back through recent changes, in order, with syntax coloring, inside vim etc.)

Comment: I'd argue that commit logs are better indicators of progress than anything else. Even if you have unfinished changes, it's possible to add a message to `git stash`.

Comment: FTR I agree with the general sentiment here: use VCS. Better yet, use DVCS and microcommit!

Comment: Another use case: I just spent 5 minutes refactoring too aggressively. Now a ton of unit tests are failing and I have no idea what I broke. I want to undo until the tests pass again. Yes, if I thought to check into version control before refactoring it would have been fine, but I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could come a long way with `undolist`:

```
:bufdo echo expand('%') | undolist
```

Results in, e.g. for a simple editing session:

```
SpiritParser.cpp
number changes  when               saved
     1       1  13:57:51
SpiritParser.h
number changes  when               saved
     1       1  13:57:55
```

To do this for all visible windows, do `windo` instead of `bufdo`. If you have multiple tabs, make that

```
:tabdo windo echo expand('%') | undolist
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using some kind of version control: Git, Mercurial, Subversion, whatever…

Each morning you can read your project's log and go through previous commits to see what changed, you can create branches to work on specific features, you write clean and descriptive commit message in order to better understand your previous changes, etc.

Or you could do something like `:windo u`. But that sounds messy.